# Open multiple QGIS projects via PyQGIS simultaneously in different threads

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgs, multithreading

I'm writing a standalone PyQGIS application. When the method qgis() is called in a new thread, it's supposed to open a QGIS project (with one layer in it) and close it again:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

from qgis.core import *

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.4", True)


def qgis(number):
    qgs.initQgis()
    print('{} started'.format(number))

    QgsProject.instance().read('D:/aGIS/pyqgis/multitest/testprojekt.qgz')

    qgs.exitQgis()
    print('{} stopped'.format(number))


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    executor.submit(qgis, '1')
    executor.submit(qgis, '2')
    executor.submit(qgis, '3')
```

Unfortunately, this is what the console says:

> Type conversion already registered from type QPair to type 
>   QtMetaTypePrivate::QPairVariantInterfaceImpl
>
> 3 started
>
> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
>
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QList'
>
> (Make sure 'QList' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
>
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QList'
>
> (Make sure 'QList' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
>
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QDomDocument'
>
> (Make sure 'QDomDocument' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
>
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QList'
>
> (Make sure 'QList' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
>
> 1 stopped

And then Python crashes. I made some experiments with moving

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.4", True)
```

into the function, resulting in slighty different errors but nevertheless it's not working. Am I making a mistake or is it just not possible loading multiple project instances at once?

Comment: without reading the qgis code in this moment, but your code does it make sense? Project is a Singleton (see the call to instance() method ), so you can't have different project at the same time in the same QgsApplication. The only fact your code is rising is that read method (or init) are not therad safe... but it's a not correct use of the API.